# Find equation for nth term of a sequence

Tags: loops, sequence

Using a for loop, I can calculate the nth term of a sequence. **How do I derive a formula for the nth term** without using the for loop.
The sequence goes as follows: 5, 12, 26, 54, 110, 222, 446...

I thought this was the way to go, but I got "Time limit exceeded" on a competitive programming website.

```
x = 5
for i in range(n):
    x = (x * 2) + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula inside the print function will give you nth term, where n = 1,2,3,4,....

```
n = int(input())
print(5 * (2**(n-1)) + 2 * (2**(n-1) - 1))
```